# Why I am not getting the result back from the async function in the useEffect Hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I got this api.

```
 public async getWizardItem(
    userId,
    type,
    signal,
  )
    const axiosInstance = await this.axios;
    return axiosInstance
      .get(`${this.BASE_URL}/wizardStepItems/${userId}/${type}`, { signal })
      .then(({ data }) => data);
  }
```

And Here is my component that I am using the api function.

```
const AddWizardItemContainer = ({ outcome, classes, transitionDelay }: any) => {
  const userId = useUserId();
  const [outcomeItemCount, setOutcomeItemCount] = useState<number>(0);

  const testFilter = useCallback(
    async (outcome) => {
      const response = await tpService.getWizardItem(
        userId,
        getWizardItemGetPayload(
          outcome.parameters?.wizardScreenName as MigraineWizardSuggestionScreen
        )
        // abortController.current.signal
      );
      console.log(response) //==NOT WORKING==
      const filteredResponse = filterItems(
        response,
        outcome.parameters.items,
        userId
      );
      return filteredResponse.length;
    },
    [userId]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('hello');
    const response = testFilter(outcome);
    response.then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    });
  }, [outcome.parameters.items.length, outcome, testFilter]);

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

As you can see I am trying to `console.log` in the useEffect

I can only see the `hello` response not the response from the `response.then`

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: If you add a log before `return axiosInstance` do you see it execute? If you add a log to the `.then(({ data }) => data);` do you ever see that? Seems like your `getWizardItem` method is returning a Promise that never settles (rejects or fulfills).

Comment: can you `console.log` something in the `.catch` of your `response` to see if the promise resolve something ?